# How can I extract the deb files from the ubuntu iso?

Tags: installation

How can I extract the deb files of ubuntu 12.10 from the official iso, I am trying to cut the download time, only some packages are in `/pool/main`

The rest seem to be in a virtual fs in `/casper/`.

How can I extract the deb files?

Comment: does it need to be from a cd or an iso file specifically ?
i ask because you could always wget a mirror site recursively grabbing only files with a .deb filetype instead..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the debs Ubuntu uses are installed into a chroot before generating the ISO image, so you can't just get them back. If you unsquash the filesystem, you'll see it looks like just a root filesystem. For example, this is a truncated view of `ls`:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 12 16:59 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 12 16:59 boot
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 12 16:56 dev
drwxr-xr-x 134 root root 12288 Oct 12 16:59 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct  9 08:59 home
```

...

If you want to mess with the chroot, you can do so as follows:

1. Mount the ISO

   ```
   sudo mount -o loop quantal-desktop-i386.iso tmpiso
   ```
2. Copy the squashfs out

   ```
   cp tmpiso/q/casper/filesystem.squashfs /tmp
   ```
3. Unsquash the filesystem

   ```
   sudo unsquashfs filesystem.squashfs
   ```
4. This will unpack the filesystem into squashfs-root.
5. Make your changes.
6. Recompress with squashfs.
7. Use ISO master to replace the filesystem.squashfs with the one you modified.
8. Rebuild the ISO with ISO master.

Comment: err, do you know if `cdromupgrade` will be available in the future ?

Answer (score 2):

- Mount the iso.
- Copy squashfs and unsquash it.
- in the extracted folder i'd execute this from the shell.

  `find -name "*.deb" -type f -execdir cp {} ~/Desktop/thefolder_you_choose/ \;`

  This finds all .deb files and dumps all of them (without the folder structure) in your destination folder.

Comment: doing a recursive wget only searching for deb files in a mirror brings back all deb files in a folder tree.. to which you can execute the same command if you want all the deb files in one spot..

Comment: I don't see any debs in my unsquashed filesystem

Comment: yes i agree me neither.. i just got a minute to test it all out.. and your best bet (if you want all the debs from the ubuntu and i mean all possible ones.. ) would be to wget all possible files from  a ubuntu mirror..  but this option will leave you with all the files in a file tree ,then you run my commend to put them all in one unique folder.. 
if you don't mind me asking,why is it you want all the .deb files ?